# Internet Explorer 11 aborting Requests Win 8.1

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a problem when accessing my site in Internet Explorer 11.

Requests are Aborted about half the time, within <1ms when I try to load a page too soon after a previous request to the same site (not necessarily the same page).

**Symptoms:**

- If I click on a link within a short while (1 min?) after loading a page. I get an error page

> This page can’t be displayed
>   Make sure the web address https://my.domain.com is correct

- The Developer Tools show `(Aborted)` in the `Result` column.
- If I try to reload the page with F5 or by clicking in the reload icon in the address bar, the page will load correctly.
- If I reload the page using a link to itself (e.g. clicking *Home* on the home page) the Developer Tools will show `navigate` or `click` in the *Initiator* column, the request will be aborted if it's too soon after the last request.
- I can use F5 (*Initiator*/`refresh`) as many times as I like without waiting and the page will load every time. According to the Developer Tools, the request is first aborted immediately and then retried with *Initiator* being blank on the second (successful) attempt.
- I don't have the same problem on other machines with IE 11

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm accessing the site via https://

I have no problems in any other browser I've tried. Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera.

When I access the webapp on my localhost development copy, I have no problems in IE.

The webapp is hosted on a sub-domain, on a different server to the main domain.

I've tried things like comparing my DNS set-up and Internet Settings to the other machines where this problem doesn't occur.

Has anyone come across a similar issue/fix?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @YASHDAVE far as I remember, this happened only on my development machine (other users were not affected) and clearing the browser cache solved the issue, see my answer below

Answer (score -1):

I finally had the idea of **clearing the browser history.**

This happened by coincidence as I was working on some .css changes at the time and those changes didn't seem to get reflected when reloading the page.

I cleared Temporary Internet files, Cookies and History. I assume clearing Temporary Internet files is what cured the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me....